# Does $\sup_{x \in (-r,r)} |f^{(n)}(x)| \leq A^n n!$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis

Let 
\begin{align}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
e^{-1/x} \quad &\text{if $x > 0$},\\\\
0 &\text{if $x \leq 0$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
I have already shown that $f(x)$ has derivatives of all orders at $x=0$, and that $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Also, I showed that $f^{(n)}(x) = P_n(1/x)e^{-1/x}$ for $x >0$ and some polynomial $P_n$.

I need to determine if $$\sup_{x \in (-r,r)} |f^{(n)}(x)| \leq A^n n!$$ holds for all $n$, some positive constant $A$, and an open interval $(-r,r)$. I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Induction looks a good bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the derivatives at zero vanish, the "mean value" Taylor's theorem (more specifically what Wikipedia calls the "Lagrange form") says that for all positive $n$ and all $0<x<r$ there exists $0\leq \xi\leq x$ such that
$$e^{-1/x}=\frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}x^n.$$

Given $A,r>0$, picking any $n>\max(Ae,1/r)$ and setting $x=1/n$, we get that there exists $0<\xi<1/n$ such that
$$f^{(n)}(\xi)=(n/e)^nn! > A^nn!$$

Alternatively, if you are willing to use complex analysis, the [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) gives the stronger fact that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} |f^{(n)}(x)/n!|^{1/n}=1/x$ for each $x>0$, because $e^{-1/x}$ has an essential singularity at zero.